# Why doesn't my Normal mode mapping work when it follows 'd' (delete)?

Tags: key-bindings

I use `d/` a lot, so I decided to map `/` as follows:

`:nnoremap <leader>j /` (where `<leader>` is my space bar)

To my surprise, `d<leader>j` doesn't work. Why is that? I expect it to behave like `d/`.

I should add that `<leader>j` alone triggers the `/`, so it is indeed correctly mapped!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you hit `d`, an *operator*, you enter [*Operator-pending*](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#mapmode-o) [*mode*](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#omap-info). Vim will then wait for a *motion* command to be entered. In other words, when you  follow `d` with `<leader>j` that's not happening in Normal mode...the mode for which you've mapped those keys.

For Operator-pending mode you need to use the [`:omap`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#:omap) family of mapping commands, so...

```
:onoremap <leader>j /
```

Fortunately, there's a mapping type, [`:map`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#:map), that encompasses both Operator-pending and Normal mode so you can kill two birds with one stone using

```
:noremap <leader>j /
```

However, this also includes Visual and Select modes so you need to be mindful of that. If that causes problems then just create two mappings (`:omap` and `:nmap` types).